# Function with SQL query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function that returns a SELECTed resultset. 
When I call my postgres function like this `select * from  tst_dates_func()` I get an error as shown below:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "tst_dates_func" line 3 at SQL statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Context: PL/pgSQL function "tst_dates_func" line 3 at SQL statement
```

Here is the function I created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tst_dates_func() 
    RETURNS TABLE( date_value date, date_id int, date_desc varchar) as
$BODY$   
BEGIN
    select a.date_value, a.date_id, a.date_desc from dates_tbl a;
END;
$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am not sure why I am getting the above error. I would like to run `select * from tst_dates_func();` 
and get data back. Or further join the result set if needed. What is the problem here?

Comment: Please see the examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-EXAMPLES

Comment: LANGUAGE should be SQL, shouldn't it?

Comment: I need it to be plpgsql function. Plus with language being SQL, i would need to put the query statement into string with quotations and I don't want to do that.

Comment: @ImtiazAhmad: with `language sql` you can use the same `$body$` quoting as with `plpgsql`. The quoting style has nothing to do with the language.

Comment: When I use the `language sql`, it doesnt compile the function. I get an error. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 5:     select a.date_value, a.date_id, a.date_desc from dates_t...`
            ^

Comment: @HorseVoice: if you remove the BEGIN and END, the function will compile if the language is SQL.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Do it as plain SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tst_dates_func() 
    RETURNS TABLE( date_value date, date_id int, date_desc varchar) as
$BODY$   
    select a.date_value, a.date_id, a.date_desc from dates_tbl a;

$BODY$
      LANGUAGE sql;
```

If you really need plpgsql use `return query`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tst_dates_func() 
    RETURNS TABLE( date_value date, date_id int, date_desc varchar) as
$BODY$   
BEGIN
    perform SELECT dblink_connect('remote_db');
    return query
    select a.date_value, a.date_id, a.date_desc from dates_tbl a;

END;
$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to establish a dblink within the function too. Before executing the return query resultset. So here is something I would like to add before the return query clause and when I do add it, I get a similar error as above mentioned. `SELECT dblink_connect('remote_db')` How can I include that in the above plpgsql function? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto, +1 great!.

Comment: Working nicely, thanks. But how do I drop the '()' around the results? (apart from cutting them away using unixs cut)

Comment: Might need and additional `RETURN;` in [PostgreSQL 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

Answer (score 3):

In PLPGSQL - use RETURN QUERY

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tst_dates_func() 
    RETURNS TABLE( date_value date, date_id int, date_desc varchar) as
$BODY$   
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY (select a.date_value, a.date_id, a.date_desc from dates_tbl a);
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: when you answer it is recommended to specify some description to your answer.

Comment: Particularly since the other answer already posted some code that apparently works. What does your answer offer that the other one doesn't?

Comment: My answer address the use in LANGUAGE PLPGSQL; - as was in the original questions

The first answer suggested using LANGUAGE SQL instead of plpgsql
When need other functionality of PlPgsql - this is the syntax that works

Am I missing something?

Comment: The first answer suggests both. I think separating your description from the actual code clarifies some of what you meant to add. Which is still already in the accepted answer, albeit with slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it as plain SQL as I needed to enter some data into a database for further processing and wanted to create a variable. Or at least I did not figure out the correct syntax for that. And the accepted answer had code I did not need, such as connecting to the database, as I ran this from inside pgAdmin with a connection setup already. I also had to drop the function when I made edits to it.

I was using this for inserting a geometry for intersection. A different use case and example could help someone else. This also shows how to then view this data and use it just like a table.

```sql
-- Get a geojson shape inside of postgres for further use
DROP FUNCTION fun();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun()
    RETURNS TABLE (geometry geometry) AS
$BODY$   
DECLARE geojson TEXT;
BEGIN
    geojson := '{
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[[[-90.9516399548092,39.8942337977775],[-90.9513913202472,39.8936939306154],[-90.9522805177147,39.8937108246505],[-90.9549542293894,39.8937616571416],[-90.954948768846,39.8945506794343],[-90.9531755591848,39.894492766522],[-90.9531770788457,39.8942868819087],[-90.9516399548092,39.8942337977775]]],
        "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}},
        }';
    return query (SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson) AS geometry);
END;
$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- View test insert
SELECT * FROM fun()
```