# PostgreSQL: Query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to fetch data from remote db by using dblink through function but getting an error `query has no destination for result data`. I am using plpgsql language to do the same.

**Function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun()
  RETURNS text AS
$$
begin
select dblink_connect(
      'port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=****');

WITH a AS (
SELECT *
FROM dblink(
    'SELECT slno,fname,mname,lname
    FROM    remote_tbl'
     ) AS t (slno int, fname text, mname text, lname text)
)
, b AS (
INSERT INTO temptab1
SELECT slno, name
FROM   a
)
, c AS (
INSERT INTO temptab2
SELECT slno, name
FROM   a
)
INSERT INTO temptab3
SELECT slno, name
FROM   a;


select dblink_disconnect();
end;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Calling Function**:

```sql
SELECT fun();
```

> ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Comment: @bma, Sorry! But I am not getting where do I replace PERFORM?

Comment: I deleted my comment, I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function with SQL query has no destination for result data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964790/function-with-sql-query-has-no-destination-for-result-data)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The stored procedure won't just return the result of the last SELECT.  You need to actually return the value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun() RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
    --- ....
    RETURN(SELECT dblink_disconnect());
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You're getting the error because Postgres expects the function to return something of type text, but your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please show your current code, we can't see it... Did you also change "select dblink_connect" ? Every result must have a destination or use PERFORM instead of SELECT.

Comment: @Frank Heikens, +1 Yeah I got it. Well! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Use a **plain SQL function instead of PL/PgSQL**, or use `SELECT INTO` and ordinary `RETURN`.

Answer (score 5):

Reason for the error you're getting is because there is no **return** in between your **BEGIN** and **END** for example:

```
    BEGIN
        update mytable set lastcodeused = to_char(cast(lastcodeused as INTEGER)+1, 'FM999999999999999999') where 
        classid = classIdVar and appid= appIdInt 
        RETURNING concat(pageUniqueCode,lastcodeused) as pageUniqueCode
        into taskcode;
        return taskcode;
    END;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have this error using a pgplsql procedure or function, and you are sure that the return is defined correctly, there exists a different non-intuitive cause. I needed some time to realize this so I think it is worth sharing. I had a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "db".fn_x(
    id integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(b_val varchar(100), c_val varchar(100)) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
var_b_val varchar(100);
var_c_val varchar(100);

BEGIN
    select var_b, var_c
        -- Missing INTO clause was the cause of the error.
        var_b_val, var_c_val
        from "db".table_y where y_id = id;

    return query(select var_b_val, var_c_val);
END;
$BODY$;
```

Just adding that missing `INTO` clause made the function work correctly.

In conclusion, this error can also trigger on silent syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT 2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at SQL statement
```

So, I replaced [SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) with [PERFORM statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
  -- SELECT 2;
  PERFORM 2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------

(1 row)
```

And, I created a PL/pgSQL function as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT 2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at SQL statement
```

So, I replaced `SELECT` statement with [RETURN statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  -- SELECT 2;
  RETURN 2; -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or, I put `SELECT` statement in `RETURN` statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT 2); -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       2
(1 row)
```