# Postgres function, getting "query has no destination for result data", don't want to use table result type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am writing a simple postgres function. The result of this function should be a row of the "events" table. I have the following:

```
create or replace function featured_event() returns setof events as
$$
begin
select events.* from events where featured is true;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I don't want to hardcode the columns, but instead use the structure from the existing table as the return type.

This is **not** a duplicate of [Function with SQL query has no destination for result data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964790/function-with-sql-query-has-no-destination-for-result-data) as I do not want to use the `table` result type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL function:

```
create or replace function featured_event() returns setof events as
$$
    select events.* from events where featured is true;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

In plpgsql you should use `return query`:

```
create or replace function featured_event_plpgsql() returns setof events as
$$
begin
    return query select events.* from events where featured is true;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `return query` is what I needed. Thank you!