# SELECT raises exception in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to implement a loop inside a function but I receive this error:

> ERROR query has no destination for result data

The code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  my_function(ill int, ndx_ bigint) RETURNS int AS
$$
DECLARE
    found_id int;
BEGIN
    FOR found_id IN 1..25 LOOP
        SELECT 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT my_function( 0,79 );
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946735/postgresql-query-has-no-destination-for-result-data

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer ,and what? This is completly not the answer.

Comment: `SELECT 1;` I think he means this. "Query" = `SELECT 1;` "has not destination".

Comment: @Anonymous-SOS, I think you are right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964790/function-with-sql-query-has-no-destination-for-result-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**The manual:**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT)

> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or `SELECT` query but
> discard the result, for example when calling a function that has
> side-effects but no useful result value. To do this in PL/pgSQL, use
> the `PERFORM` statement:
>
> ```
> PERFORM query;
> ```

Unless you assign the result, replace

```
SELECT 1;
```

with

```
PERFORM 1;
```