# In Plpgsql, how to use user defined function in another user defined function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a simple user defined function as following:

```
create or replace function test()
returns table (a float, b float) as
$$
begin
 drop table if exists test1;
 create table test1(a float, b float);
 insert into test1 values(1,1),(2,1),(3,3);
 return query select * from test1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I have another user defined function. In this one, I want to call the function above.

```
create or replace function test2()
returns table (a float) as
$$
begin
 select test();
 return query select a+b from test1;
end;
$$language plpgsql;
```

after this, when I do:

```
select test2();
```

It gives me an error:

> query has no destination for result data.

If I make my second function as the following:

```
create or replace function test2()
returns table (a float) as
$$
 select a+b from test();
$$language sql;
```

Then I do `select test2();`

It runs correctly. I think the reason why this doesn't work is when I return something from sql function, it returns a table, but when I return something from a plpgsql function, it returns something look like a tuple. For example (1,2). 1 will be the first attribute of the table, 2 will be the second one. This is just a simple example, I can use sql instead of plpgsql to solve this problem. However, in my real project, I really want to call a plpgsql function in another plpgsql function.

Then main structure of my program will look like the following:

```
plpgsql function 1
plpgsql function 2
plpgsql function 3
```

In my main plpgsql function, I want to call all these three functions. Does anyone have a idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says:

> query has no destination for result data.

Meaning, you cannot execute a `SELECT` in a plpgsql function without destination for the result.
Use [**`PERFORM`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) instead of `SELECT` if you want to discard the result.

Related:

- [SELECT raises exception in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230750/select-raises-exception-in-pl-pgsql-function/37234043#37234043)

Comment: Thanks. it will be perform from (function).