# Conditional SELECT clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building a dashboard and I need to return certain columns from a table depending on a sensor's choice. The user selects a sensor and the database returns some columns depending on which sensor the user chose.

The approach I had in mind was something simple like this:

```sql
if ${sensor} = '1' then
    select time, temperature from tbl;
elsif ${sensor} = '2' then
    select time, humidity from tbl;
else
    --return nothing
end if;
```

My table is made up of a timestamp column and several other float columns, each of them containing the value of a physical variable at that certain time (temperature, pressure, humidity, height and weight). So if the user selects for example Sensor 1, a thermometer, my query should return the time and temperature columns. Some of the sensors could also return more than one physical variable, so I would need to return a table with three columns, time, height and weight.

I'm using Grafana and I'm able to read the chosen variable without any problem, but I am unable to build a table with the columns of my choice depending on this value.

I thought about writing a function that returned a table, but this is way too far from my SQL knowledge and I was pretty sure this could be done with plain SQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) You will have to do this in a function, plain SQL does not support `if/else` 2) `DO` anonymous functions can't return anything so they will not be of much use. 3) Do as the `Hint` suggests and use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT` per [plpgsql statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL). 4) Spend some time reading through [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

Comment: Is `variable` in this case part of your table?

Comment: @BeRT2me no, the user selects a value for this variable and the query changes accordingly, but the table doesn't contain this value

Answer (score 0):

The same `SELECT` cannot return a different number of columns. You can issue a different `SELECT` from your client program. Else, you need to aggregate multiple columns *somehow*: a list of values, an array, or a document type like JSON - using [`json_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) for the purpose:

```sql
SELECT time
     , CASE ${sensor}
       WHEN 1 THEN json_build_object('temperature', temperature)
       WHEN 2 THEN json_build_object('humidity', humidity)
       WHEN 3 THEN json_build_object('height', height, 'weight', weight)  -- two columns!
       END AS variable_column
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ${sensor} IN (1, 2, 3);  -- return nothing for other numbers
```

The second part of your question is an amalgam of independent issues:

- You cannot execute `SELECT` in a PL/pgSQL code block without an assignment target.
- You cannot return anything from a `DO` statement. You need a [`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) (or, to a limited extent, a [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)) for that.

See:

- [SELECT raises exception in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230750/select-raises-exception-in-pl-pgsql-function/37234043#37234043)

Comment: Thank you Erwin, I edited the question to provide more information on the scope

Comment: I think I need to dig deeper into `json_build_object` because I have no idea how it works... Probably a noob question, but why does have to be the _same select_ and not 3 different ones? If only I could choose what select to perform depending on the sensor's choice...

Comment: You can choose your `SELECT` *in client code*. Or you can write a server-side function, but a function has a single, immutable return type ...